# eslint import/no-extraneous-dependencies fails to resolve the depencency

Tags: javascript, eslint, brunch

I compiled javascript code into **app.js** using **brunch**

**eslint** gives me the following output, however in my browser everything works perfect.

#### Error

```
error: 'frontend' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S frontend' to add it (import/no-extraneous-dependencies) at templates/base.html:41:9:
  39 |       <script src="{% static 'handlebars/templates.js' %}"></script>
  40 |       <script>
> 41 |         require('frontend/js/index');
     |         ^
  42 |       </script>
  43 |     {% endblock javascript %}
  44 |     {% block events %}


error: Unable to resolve path to module 'frontend/js/index' (import/no-unresolved) at templates/base.html:41:17:
  39 |       <script src="{% static 'handlebars/templates.js' %}"></script>
  40 |       <script>
> 41 |         require('frontend/js/index');
     |                 ^
  42 |       </script>
  43 |     {% endblock javascript %}
  44 |     {% block events %}
```

#### My environment

```
Brunch: 2.10.10
Node.js: 6.11.2
NPM: 3.10.10
Operating system: Fedora 26
Code editor: emacs
```

#### Code

Javascript code lives inside django template

```
{% load staticfiles i18n %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}CRM{% endblock title %}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    {% block css %}
      {% if debug %}
        <link href="{% static 'vendor.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'app.css' %}"   rel="stylesheet">
      {% else %}
        <link href="{% static 'vendor.min.css' %}"rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'app.min.css' %}"  rel="stylesheet">
      {% endif %}
    {% endblock css %}
  </head>

  <body "page-top">
    {% include 'includes/header.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% block javascript %}
      {% if debug %}
        <script src="{% static 'vendor.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
      {% else %}
        <script src="{% static 'vendor.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'app.min.js' %}"></script>
      {% endif %}
      <script src="{% static 'handlebars/templates.js' %}"></script>
      <script>
        require('frontend/js/index');
      </script>
    {% endblock javascript %}
    {% block events %}
    {% endblock events %}
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Compiled app.js lives in .frontend/app.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var globals = typeof global === 'undefined' ? self : global;
  if (typeof globals.require === 'function') return;

  var modules = {};
  var cache = {};
  var aliases = {};
  var has = {}.hasOwnProperty;

  var expRe = /^\.\.?(\/|$)/;
  var expand = function(root, name) {
    var results = [], part;
    var parts = (expRe.test(name) ? root + '/' + name : name).split('/');
    for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
      part = parts[i];
      if (part === '..') {
        results.pop();
      } else if (part !== '.' && part !== '') {
        results.push(part);
      }
    }
    return results.join('/');
  };

  var dirname = function(path) {
    return path.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
  };

  var localRequire = function(path) {
    return function expanded(name) {
      var absolute = expand(dirname(path), name);
      return globals.require(absolute, path);
    };
  };

  var initModule = function(name, definition) {
    var hot = hmr && hmr.createHot(name);
    var module = {id: name, exports: {}, hot: hot};
    cache[name] = module;
    definition(module.exports, localRequire(name), module);
    return module.exports;
  };

  var expandAlias = function(name) {
    return aliases[name] ? expandAlias(aliases[name]) : name;
  };

  var _resolve = function(name, dep) {
    return expandAlias(expand(dirname(name), dep));
  };

  var require = function(name, loaderPath) {
    if (loaderPath == null) loaderPath = '/';
    var path = expandAlias(name);

    if (has.call(cache, path)) return cache[path].exports;
    if (has.call(modules, path)) return initModule(path, modules[path]);

    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + name + "' from '" + loaderPath + "'");
  };

  require.alias = function(from, to) {
    aliases[to] = from;
  };

  var extRe = /\.[^.\/]+$/;
  var indexRe = /\/index(\.[^\/]+)?$/;
  var addExtensions = function(bundle) {
    if (extRe.test(bundle)) {
      var alias = bundle.replace(extRe, '');
      if (!has.call(aliases, alias) || aliases[alias].replace(extRe, '') === alias + '/index') {
        aliases[alias] = bundle;
      }
    }

    if (indexRe.test(bundle)) {
      var iAlias = bundle.replace(indexRe, '');
      if (!has.call(aliases, iAlias)) {
        aliases[iAlias] = bundle;
      }
    }
  };

  require.register = require.define = function(bundle, fn) {
    if (bundle && typeof bundle === 'object') {
      for (var key in bundle) {
        if (has.call(bundle, key)) {
          require.register(key, bundle[key]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      modules[bundle] = fn;
      delete cache[bundle];
      addExtensions(bundle);
    }
  };

  require.list = function() {
    var list = [];
    for (var item in modules) {
      if (has.call(modules, item)) {
        list.push(item);
      }
    }
    return list;
  };

  var hmr = globals._hmr && new globals._hmr(_resolve, require, modules, cache);
  require._cache = cache;
  require.hmr = hmr && hmr.wrap;
  require.brunch = true;
  globals.require = require;
})();

(function() {
var global = typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window;
var process;
var __makeRelativeRequire = function(require, mappings, pref) {
  var none = {};
  var tryReq = function(name, pref) {
    var val;
    try {
      val = require(pref + '/node_modules/' + name);
      return val;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.toString().indexOf('Cannot find module') === -1) {
        throw e;
      }

      if (pref.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1) {
        var s = pref.split('/');
        var i = s.lastIndexOf('node_modules');
        var newPref = s.slice(0, i).join('/');
        return tryReq(name, newPref);
      }
    }
    return none;
  };
  return function(name) {
    if (name in mappings) name = mappings[name];
    if (!name) return;
    if (name[0] !== '.' && pref) {
      var val = tryReq(name, pref);
      if (val !== none) return val;
    }
    return require(name);
  }
};
require.register("frontend/js/config.js", function(exports, require, module) {
'use strict';

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Common config values should go here
// =======================================================
var common = {};

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Local config
// =======================================================
var local = Object.assign({}, common, {
  api: {
    host: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/'
  }
});

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Development config
// =======================================================
var development = Object.assign({}, common, {
  api: {
    host: 'http://development.com/api/v1/'
  }
});

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Staging config
// =======================================================
var staging = Object.assign({}, common, {
  api: {
    host: 'http://staging.com/api/v1/'
  }
});

// -------------------------------------------------------
// Production config
// =======================================================
var production = Object.assign({}, common, {
  api: {
    host: 'http://production.com/api/v1/'
  }
});

/**
 * Returns the configuration based on domain
 * @returns {object}
 */
function getConfig() {
  switch (window.location.hostname) {
    case 'localhost':
    case '127.0.0.1':
      return local;
    case 'dev.yourdomain.com':
      return development;
    case 'staging.yourdomain.com':
      return staging;
    case 'yourdomain.com':
      return production;
    default:
      throw new Error('Unknown environment: ' + String(window.location.hostname));
  }
}

/**
 * Define actual configuration to be used
 */
var config = Object.assign({}, getConfig());

/**
 * Returns the configuration parameter
 * @param {str} key - config's key
 */
function getItem(key) {
  return key in config ? config[key] : null;
}

/**
 * Sets the configuration parameter
 * @param {str} key - config's key
 * @param {str|number|boolean} value - config's key value
 */
function setItem(key, value) {
  config[key] = value;
}

config = Object.assign(config, {
  getItem: getItem,
  setItem: setItem
});

module.exports = config;

});

require.register("frontend/js/index.js", function(exports, require, module) {
"use strict";

(function () {
  function init() {
    // put your initialization code here
    // console.log('Init');
  }

  return init;
})()();

});

require.alias("process/browser.js", "process");process = require('process');require.register("___globals___", function(exports, require, module) {


// Auto-loaded modules from config.npm.globals.
window.jQuery = require("jquery");
window["$"] = require("jquery");
window.bootstrap = require("bootstrap");
window.selectpicker = require("bootstrap-select");
window.datepicker = require("bootstrap-datepicker");


});})();require('___globals___');


//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

#### .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    'browser': true,
    'commonjs': true,
    'es6': true,
    'jquery': true
  },
  plugins: [
    'html',
    'import'
  ],
  extends: [
    'airbnb-base',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings'
  ],
  rules: {
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
    'no-alert': 'off'
  }
};
```

I understand I can turn off the rules completely, but how to resolve this issue properly?

I guess I need to do something with eslint import resolver, but not sure what from their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

eslint understands that every package that doesn't have a relative import should exist in your node_modules, just as regular require would work in node and therefore that's the reason why you are getting this error.

your project configuration may allow you to require that module without adding `./` in its path but its not the default behavior for javascript modules.